# Python Sklearn Covariance Matrix diagonal entries incorrect?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, correlation, covariance, pca

I am trying to perform PCA on some data. From my knowledge, the correlation matrix should have entries of `1` along the main diagonal. This is not what I am seeing for `.get_covariance()` in sklearn PCA. I am wondering why this is the case?
For my own purposes, I can just perform a scaling of the matrix to obtain a matrix with diagonal entries of `1`, but I was just wondering, since I have **already standardized** my data, why are the diagonal entries still not `1`?

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: import numpy as np                                                                                                                      

In [3]: from sklearn.decomposition import PCA                                                                                                   

In [4]: df = pd.read_csv('myTable.csv')                                                                                                         

In [5]: df                                                                                                                                      
Out[5]:                                                                                                                                         
         a1        a2        a3        a4        a5                                                                                             
0 -0.559104  0.185914 -2.331367  0.231150  0.357008                                                                                             
1  0.769835 -0.408685  0.375754  0.051397 -0.075885                                                                                             
2 -1.376530 -0.764808 -2.383611 -0.327153  1.746765                                                                                             
3 -0.830105 -0.197574  1.835807 -0.695089  0.881297                                                                                             
4 -0.991861  1.089319 -0.164139 -0.335003  0.795937                                                                                             
5 -1.132968 -2.240598 -0.101935  0.680038 -0.033921                                                                                             
6 -1.205631 -1.492009 -0.602400 -0.065256 -0.494267                                                                                             
7 -1.210978 -1.220986 -0.017062  0.024422 -0.224585                                                                                             
8 -0.332957  2.114870  0.818108  0.612831 -1.879758                                                                                             
9 -0.350612 -0.563872  0.869303 -0.325626 -0.372874                                                                                             

In [6]: df = (df-df.mean())/df.std()                                                                                                            

In [7]: pca = PCA()                                                                                                                             

In [8]: pca.fit(df)                                                                                                                             
Out[8]: PCA(copy=True, n_components=None, whiten=False)  

In [10]: pca.explained_variance_, pca.components_, pca.get_covariance()                                                                         
Out[10]:                                                                                                                                        
(array([ 1.8780651 ,  1.1526052 ,  0.78052872,  0.55167761,  0.13712337]),                                                                      
 array([[-0.47790108, -0.36036503, -0.38619941, -0.35716396,  0.60417838],                                                                      
        [ 0.25426743,  0.32305024,  0.47784502, -0.72831952,  0.26870322],                                                                      
        [-0.17613902, -0.7303121 ,  0.6250759 , -0.05118019, -0.20562097],                                                                      
        [ 0.82132736, -0.45982165, -0.21938834,  0.03274499,  0.25452296],                                                                      
        [ 0.03681087, -0.14485808, -0.42855924, -0.58162955, -0.67505936]]),                                                                    
 array([[ 0.9       ,  0.30943895,  0.29916112,  0.12605405, -0.32333097],                                                                      
        [ 0.30943895,  0.9       ,  0.14715469,  0.00295615, -0.24279645],                                                                      
        [ 0.29916112,  0.14715469,  0.9       , -0.13683409, -0.38167791],                                                                      
        [ 0.12605405,  0.00295615, -0.13683409,  0.9       , -0.56418468],                                                                      
        [-0.32333097, -0.24279645, -0.38167791, -0.56418468,  0.9       ]]))
```

**Closed**
The problem was with my standardization. I was supposed to use `df.std(ddof=0)` as suggested by `Tonechas`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to normalize the standard deviation by N rather than by N-1 (which is the default value). This can be changed using the `ddof` parameter in the call to [`pandas.DataFrame.std()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.std.html) like this:

```
In [146]: from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

In [147]: df
Out[147]: 
         a1        a2        a3        a4        a5
0 -0.559104  0.185914 -2.331367  0.231150 -0.559104
1  0.769835 -0.408685  0.375754  0.051397  0.769835
2 -1.376530 -0.764808 -2.383611 -0.327153 -1.376530
3 -0.830105 -0.197574  1.835807 -0.695089 -0.830105
4 -0.991861  1.089319 -0.164139 -0.335003 -0.991861
5 -1.132968 -2.240598 -0.101935  0.680038 -1.132968
6 -1.205631 -1.492009 -0.602400 -0.065256 -1.205631
7 -1.210978 -1.220986 -0.017062  0.024422 -1.210978
8 -0.332957  2.114870  0.818108  0.612831 -0.332957
9 -0.350612 -0.563872  0.869303 -0.325626 -0.350612

In [148]: df = (df-df.mean())/df.std(ddof=0)

In [149]: pca = PCA()

In [150]: pca.fit(df)
Out[150]: 
PCA(copy=True, iterated_power='auto', n_components=None, random_state=None,
  svd_solver='auto', tol=0.0, whiten=False)

In [151]: pca.get_covariance()
Out[151]: 
array([[ 1.  ,  0.34,  0.33,  0.14,  1.  ],
       [ 0.34,  1.  ,  0.16,  0.  ,  0.34],
       [ 0.33,  0.16,  1.  , -0.15,  0.33],
       [ 0.14,  0.  , -0.15,  1.  ,  0.14],
       [ 1.  ,  0.34,  0.33,  0.14,  1.  ]])
```

Comment: so I'm not scaling/standardizing my data correctly?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, it is not necessarily ones because pca.get_covariance() returns an estimatation?

Comment: Why is that different? The data is still the same, only the representation is different.

Comment: I have scaled each column though? `df.mean()` and `df.std()` return arrays-- the means and stds of the columns.

Comment: That is probably why. I can't believe I forgot about that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

PCA and correlation matrix are different things. The correlation matrix is just the product if the centred and normalised data with its transpose (there might be slightly differering definitions in the wild) PCA is a decomposition not dissimilar to the eigen decomposition. In particular, the PCs are degeneracies aside orthogonal, so no correlations there.

Of course, the two are related, for example if all you vectors are correlated you'd expect a corresponding PC with a high weight.

Comment: Sure, but is PCA not based on the correlation matrix?

Comment: @AsheKetchum I think in its original form it doesn't normalise the lengths of the input, so it would be the covariance matrix. But you are correct that in practice many people choose to normalise. Still, it is only that one way of calculating PCA uses this matrix as an intermediate. They are not the same and do not have the same diagonal elements.

Comment: Yes, I understand. My question was why my matrix was not a correlation matrix after I had already normalized. On the other hand I have never said that PCA, an analysis, is the same as the correlation matrix, a matrix.

Comment: @AsheKetchum Ok, I suppose I misunderstood your question. Sorry about that.

Comment: No problem :) Thanks for trying to help!